# How to stop requery dynamically created databound subform on every property change?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Access 2016 Formular uses a subform that is dynamically created by code.

```
mySubForm.SourceObject = "dbo_tbl_TableName"
mySubForm.Form.RecordSource = "dbo_tbl_TableName"
mySubForm.LinkChildFields = "NameOfFK"
mySubForm.LinkMasterFields = "NameOfPK"
```

Problem: the form load 4 times the linked table.
Setting IsEnabled, Visible, locked does not prevent the problem.

Need to set my Properties, and then load the data once...
Any ideas?

thx for any help in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Where is your code located?

Comment: You can try wrapping these in `Application.Echo False` ... `Application.Echo True`

Comment: Application.Echo false/true does not work...

Comment: code is in the form load